# How to connect android using novnc?

Tags: android, emulation, vnc

First I have installed novnc and sdk in linux, each of them runs correctly, however, I don't know how to connect emulator with novnc. The following commands are used in my experience.
android list targets
android create avd -n myAVD -t 1
emulator -avd myAVD -qemu -vnc 2
vncserver
vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1
./utils/launch.sh --vnc 127.0.0.1:5901